# how to show | hide links for certain time

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing one add on for my ptc website,using php and Mysql, with the following features:

1: user will click the link

2: user will copy the output url

3: paste it in the text field

4: if the pasted value matched with the existing value, it will credit the user account.
I have done above all:

what i want to ask is.
when a  link is clicked , it should not appear to the same user for certain time , i.e. 1 hr or 4 hrs. or 24 etc etc

this is sort of manual surf for web sites.

Thanks for suggestions:

Comment: You are going to have to keep a record (in the db) of when the user clicked the link.  Then check against that when they come back.  That's the most reliable way to track it...

Comment: user part is complete. only need to know about the timings. as i have not idea how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making comment my answer, as OP seemed to like it:

You are going to have to keep a record (in the db) of when the user clicked the link. Then check against that when they come back. That's the most reliable way to track it...